# Is there a way to monitor for an incoming event under a void?

Tags: c#, events, subscribe

I'm trying to monitor incoming events under a function that loops until a message has come, is there a way or a function to do that? The only idea I got is that the events come to a preset void that I'm subscribed to, the only issue is that I need to receive under the loop so I can continue with the data.

Maybe the incoming data that I'm subscribed for could be saved on a variable so in the loop I check if the variable has been editted? Let me know your thoughts, thanks!

Comment: One possibility would be to use a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0), but without showing some code is only guessing.

Comment: How would ConcurrentQueue work? thanks for the comment @Steeeve

Comment: The event handler enqueues something, the loop dequeues something. You really have to show some code for more details...